# Passing the results of a Mysql query to a subquery on the same table

Tags: mysql, subquery

```
CREATE TABLE test (
id INT(12),
time VARCHAR(16),
group INT(2),
taken TINYINT(1),
RID int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
primary KEY (RID));


id | time | group | taken
---------------------------
1  | 13.00|   1   |   1
---------------------------
2  | 13.00|   2   |   0
---------------------------
3  | 14.00|   2   |   0
---------------------------
4  | 15.00|   2   |   0
---------------------------
5  | 12.00|   3   |   0
```

Having a table structure and sample data as above, I want to get the smallest "group" number which has not been "taken" (taken=0)

I have come with two queries :

```
SELECT * From `test` 
WHERE taken=0
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM `test`
WHERE `group` =  ( SELECT MIN(`group`) FROM `test` )
```

Can someone show me how to combine the two queries so that I can pass the results of the first query to the second query to get as below.

```
id | time | group | taken
---------------------------
2  | 13.00|   2   |   0
---------------------------
3  | 14.00|   2   |   0
---------------------------
4  | 15.00|   2   |   0
---------------------------
```

Comment: Is `taken` a property of each group? i.e. will all registers with the same value in `group` have the same value in `taken`? If so, your database is not normalized, and it would make things clearer if you moved the `taken` field to another table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the result of the first query in the second query as follows:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TEST 
WHERE `group` = (SELECT MIN(`group`) 
                 FROM `test` 
                 WHERE taken = 0)
```

Which gives you the desired result according to [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/235ef/10)

Answer (score 1):

Use the sub query to get the lowest group for taken of 0. Join your main table to the results of the sub query.

Something like this:-

```
SELECT a.* 
From `test` a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT MIN(`group`) AS min_group
    FROM `test` 
    WHERE taken=0
) b
ON a.taken = b.taken
AND a.`group` = b.min_group
```

Comment: hey thanks for helping, im getting a "Unknown column 'min_group' in 'field list'"..

Comment: Ooops, typo. Meant to put AS and typed AND

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT min(`group`) FROM (
    SELECT * FROM test
    WHERE taken = 0) 
AS t;
```